# Using SOAP::Lite based on WSDL

Tags: perl, authentication, soap, wsdl

I'm brand new to SOAP::Lite and trying to work through the [quick start](http://guide.soaplite.com/).  I have a JAMA server (requirements gathering app) that supports SOAP and I am looking at its WSDL.

Is the information I need for SOAP::Lite available in the WSDL (specifically the proxy and the namespace/uri)?

The WSDL contains this:

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:ns1="http://v3.ws.contour.jamasoftware.com/"
  xmlns:ns2="http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/xformat"
  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
  xmlns:tns="http://v3.ws.contour.jamasoftware.com"
  xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="ContourSoapServiceV3"
  targetNamespace="http://v3.ws.contour.jamasoftware.com">
<wsdl:import
  location="http://MYSERVER/jama/ws/v3/soap/ContourSoapService?wsdl=ContourSoapService.wsdl"
  namespace="http://v3.ws.contour.jamasoftware.com/"/>
<wsdl:binding name="ContourSoapServiceV3SoapBinding" type="ns1:ContourSoapService">
<soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
And a little later on...
<wsdl:operation name="getProjects">
  <soap:operation soapAction="getProjects" style="document"/>
  <wsdl:input name="getProjects">
    <soap:body use="literal"/>
  </wsdl:input>
  <wsdl:output name="getProjectsResponse">
    <soap:body use="literal"/>
  </wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
```

For future reference, I did get this mostly working, here's the code:

```
my $soap = SOAP::Lite
  -> proxy('http://MYSERVER/jama/ws/v3/soap/ContourSoapService')
  -> uri('http://v3.ws.contour.jamasoftware.com');
print "Soap is $soap\n";
# Soap is SOAP::Lite=HASH(0x7fdc24e3fb70)
```

The PERL code I have sort of runs:

```
my $service = SOAP::Lite->service('http://MYSERVER/jama/ws/v3/soap/ContourSoapService?wsdl');
print "service is $service\n";
# This says service is ContourSoapServiceV3=HASH(0x7fd244804678) which is happy
# But then I can't figure out what to do with $service
my %hash = %$service;
foreach my $key (keys %hash )
{
   print "key $key\n";
}
# service is ContourSoapServiceV3=HASH(0x7f8c8bf342f8)
# key _packager
# key _transport
# key _on_fault
# key _on_nonserialized
# key _deserializer
# key _on_action
# key _autoresult
# key _schema
my $schema = $service->_schema();
print "schema is $schema\n";
# Unrecognized method '_schema'. List of available method(s):
# getDownstreamRelationships getRelationshipsForProject addAttachmentToItem
# signBaseline clearSuspectLinksForItem deactivateProject
# and eventually:
# getVersion
# and then many more
print "Version is " . $service->getVersion(3, 6) . "\n";
# Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ./JamaItems.perl line 66.

# And if I bypass the $service it's no better:
print "Version is " . SOAP::Lite
  -> proxy('http://MYSERVER/jama/ws/v3/soap/ContourSoapService')
  -> uri('http://v3.ws.contour.jamasoftware.com')
  -> getVersion(3, 6)
  -> result . "\n";
# Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ./JamaItems.perl line 70.
```

The parameters I'm passing to getVersion() are definitely wrong, is that enough to cause the function to return nothing?  I had thought it would at least return me some kind of error ...

Answer (score 2):

I've used SOAP::Lite to talk to a .NET web-service (*.asmx format).  The web-service provides a WSDL, but that's NOT what I reference in the code.

```
  my $soap = SOAP::Lite
    -> uri('http://myserver')
    -> on_action( sub { join '/', 'http://myserver', $_[1] } )
    -> proxy('http://myserver/services/GetEmailAddress/Service.asmx');

  my $method = SOAP::Data->name('GetEmailAddress')
    ->attr({xmlns => 'http://myserver/'});

  my @params = ( SOAP::Data->name(username => "someusername") ); 
  my $email = $soap->call($method => @params)->result;
```

Everything in there I learned from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995764.aspx.  Not sure if that will help you, as you might not have an asmx-format web-service, but maybe it will!

Answer (score 2):

I discovered the magic command:

```
$soap->outputxml('true');
```

So now I can see that when I call that getProjects() function with an invalid parameter, it is in fact talking to the server and getting an error:

```
my $soap = SOAP::Lite
  -> proxy('http://MYSERVER/jama/ws/v3/soap/ContourSoapService')
  -> uri('http://v3.ws.contour.jamasoftware.com');
print "Soap is $soap\n";
# Soap is SOAP::Lite=HASH(0x7fdc24e3fb70)

my $projects = $soap->getProjects(3);
print "Projects are $projects\n\n";
# Projects are <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
# <soap:Body><soap:Fault>
#   <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
#   <faultstring>Access control</faultstring>
# </soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

So even though the WSDL was no help in learning what the parameter is supposed to be, the documentation says it's a WsAuth object, so now I just have to figure out how to create one of those.